# sqlsrv_connect character set windows-1252

Tags: php, sql, encoding, connection, sqlsrv

I am returning an hexadecimal string from a database, but it's full of question marks (??)

The encoding **i'am currently using is UTF-8** but it's not the right encoding i guess...

```
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"test", "UID"=>"tester", "PWD"=>"11111","CharacterSet" =>"UTF-8");

$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
```

After some searching around the web i found that the database may be using Windows-1252.

The problem is that **i cant define the CharacterSet of the sqlsrv to be Windows-1252.**

How can I achieve this?